# What Does the ! do in an array?

Tags: bash

I was trying to print an index number along with the value of an array.  I didn't know how to do it and figured it out via someone else's past post on this site.  They basically added a ! in the "for" statement. But I actually don't understand what the "!" is actually doing, please can someone tell me, so I can understand **why** this works (i.e. prints out the index of $i rather than the value)?

```
$ cat test6
declare -a car_models
car_models=( honda toyota bmw )

for i in "${!car_models[@]}" ## Meaning of ! in this line plz
do
echo " $i ${car_models[$i]}" 
done
$ ./test6
 0 honda
 1 toyota
 2 bmw
```

Comment: You may find this helpful: [Usage of ! in parameter expansion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247589/usage-of-in-parameter-expansion)

Comment: Yes this helps a lot.  I had no idea what to google to find that.  It's exactly what I needed, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`"${!car_models[@]}"` quite literally gives the indexes of the array `car_models`.

[From the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html):

> It is possible to obtain the keys (indices) of an array as well as the values. `${!name[@]}` and `${!name[*]}` expand to the indices assigned in array variable name. The treatment when in double quotes is similar to the expansion of the special parameters `@` and `*` within double quotes.

It works with both indexed and associative arrays:

```
$ bash -c 'a=([10]=foo bar doo); echo "${!a[@]}"'
10 11 12
$ bash -c 'declare -A aa=([foo]=123 [bar]=456); echo "${!aa[@]}"'
bar foo
```